# finding elements from two CGPoint arrays that contain the same x value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

I know how to find an array that contains the same elements of two arrays, i.e,

```
let resultArray = firstArray.filter(secondArray.contains)
```

But if both `firstArray` and `secondArray`are `CGPoint` arrays, how do I find elements that contain the same x values in both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let secoundArrayXPoints = secondArray.map{$0.x}
let resultArray = firstArray.filter{ secoundArrayXPoints.contains($0.x) }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to allocate an extra `CGPoint` array holding the `x` points of `secondArray`, you could use the following alternative

```
let resultAlt1 = firstArray
    .filter { pt in secondArray.reduce(false) { $0 || $1.x == pt.x } }
```

It's possible that the short-circuiting of `reduce` is not working quite as well as implementing this explicitly, so if performance is an issue, another alternative is

```
let resultAlt2 = firstArray.filter {
    for pt in secondArray {
        if pt.x == $0.x { return true }
    }
    return false
}
```

This is in essence the same technique as the other answers using `contains`, but without the need of an intermediate `x` points array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//your data
let search = [CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 0, y: 2), CGPoint(x: 3, y: 3)]
let queryPoints = [CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1), CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)]

//actual search
let queryX = queryPoints.map{ $0.x }
let result = search.filter{ queryX.contains($0.x) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrA: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10), CGPoint(x:15, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 20, y: 20)]

let arrB: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 30), CGPoint(x:40, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 20, y: 30)]


let arrAx = arrA.map({ $0.x })


let arrC = arrB.filter({arrAx.contains($0.x) } )
```